# Data Consolidation using Batch Script

Tags: consolidation

I have following string in text files:

```
Hostname: ABCD
Manufacturer: LENOVO
Model: 0585AL7
Domain: XYZ.COM
Is Part of Domain: True
Current Logged In User: IN\USER
Number of Processors: 1
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise 
Name: Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise |C:\Windows|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1
Organization: XYZ
RegisteredUser: XYZ
SerialNumber: 00392-918-5000002-85350
WindowsDirectory: C:\Windows
Version: 6.1.7600
Original Install Date: 20110319025551.000000+330
```

I am using below command to parse the content.

```
FINDSTR /B /S /I "Operating System" *.txt >> OsMatch.lst
FINDSTR /B /S /I "Version" *.txt >> OsMatch.lst
FINDSTR /B /S /I "Manufacturer" *.txt >> OsMatch.lst
FINDSTR /B /S /I "Domain" *.txt >> OsMatch.lst
FINDSTR /B /S /I /C:"Is Part of Domain" *.txt >> OsMatch.lst
FINDSTR /B /S /I /C:"Current Logged In User" *.txt >> OsMatch.lst
FINDSTR /B /S /I /C:"Number of Processors" *.txt >> OsMatch.lst
FINDSTR /B /S /I "RegisteredUser" *.txt >> OsMatch.lst
FINDSTR /B /S /I "Organization" *.txt >> OsMatch.lst
FINDSTR /B /S /I "SerialNumber" *.txt >> OsMatch.lst
FINDSTR /B /S /I "WindowsDirectory" *.txt >> OsMatch.lst
FINDSTR /B /S /I /C:"Original Install Date" *.txt >> OsMatch.lst

ECHO Hostname,Operating System, Version, Manufacturer, Domain, IsPartofDomain, CurrentLoggedInUser, No of Processor, 

RegisteredUser, Organization, Serial Number, WindowsDirectory, InstallDate, Location > Desktop-OS.csv

FOR /f "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%a in (OsMatch.lst) do ( set new1=%%a 
SET new2=%%c
SET new1=!new1:~0,-4!

FOR /f "tokens=1,* delims=\" %%a in ('echo !new1!') do ( 
SET new5=%%a
SET new6=%%b


FOR /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('echo !new2!') do ( 
SET new4=%%a
)
)

IF {!new6!}=={}  (echo !new5!,!new4!,NA  >> Desktop-OS.csv
) else ( echo !new6!,!new4!,!new5!  >> Desktop-OS.csv)
)
```

Output is coming in excel file, but in each row, I want output under every column as below

```
Hostname    Operating System                     Version 
ABCD        Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise           6.1.7600
```

likewise all the TABS
"Manufacturer    Domain  IsPartofDomain  CurrentLoggedInUser     No of Processor     RegisteredUser  Organization    Serial Number   WindowsDirectory    InstallDate     Location" 
.

Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: Are your forced to use a bat file? Using PowerShell would make this much more easier.

Comment: better.. if i can get in batch only... also, can u share powershell code, if possible...